# Electrical: Wiring a dimmer switch in a circuit with fixture, outlet, another switch powering 2 other fixtures

Tags: electrical, lighting, receptacle, circuit-breaker, dimmer-switch

I have a 3 gang box, and the following is all on one circuit.

Power is coming from the breaker box into a grounded outlet receptacle.

Outlet receptacle continues along to two switched devices: 1 switch controls 1 light fixture; 1 switch controls a second light fixture plus an exhaust fan.

Everything was working when I disassembled.

I replaced the light/fan switch with a new single-pole switch. I replaced the light switch with a new dimmer switch. I replaced the outlet with a new outlet.

Wired everything up the same as it was originally.

**All are working, BUT: Now, the outlet and light/fan are not hot until the dimmer switch is turned on. Furthermore the outlet and fan are reduced by the dimmer.**

Obviously the load wiring is not correct.

I don't believe I mixed up any of the wiring.

Dimmer switch wiring diagram shows "Wire to Light or Source" at both connection points. The dimmer switch supports single pole and three way configurations.

Does a dimmer switch not support my scenario?  Do I need a specific configuration for the dimmer not outlined in the instructions?

Did I mix up wiring somewhere? Everything originates from the outlet receptacle. The only wiring into the dimmer is from the outlet, and the only wiring out goes to the fixture.

Appreciate any help or insights.

**EDIT: Here are some photos of the setup.**

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AigE1xgH6ghqgqBZfwJEMK7GtYoJ3A

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel thanks for your reply, I've added a link to photos in my original question. Can take better photos or isolate wires if needed.

Comment: Really can't see which wire goes where - particularly in that collection of neutrals on the outlet. And is that tape wrapped around the switch on the right? Separate stuff out so we can see what goes where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did I mix up wiring somewhere?

Yes.

> All are working, BUT: Now, the outlet and light/fan are not hot until the dimmer switch is turned on. Furthermore the outlet and fan are reduced by the dimmer.

Apparently, you wired the outlet and fan in series with the dimmer.

Re-check your wiring and make sure the outlet and fan are fed by the hot feed in the circuit NOT from the load side of the dimmer.

Good luck and stay safe!

Comment: +1 Thank you for your reply! Is there an obvious way to check which is the hot feed coming through the outlet, or an obvious way to break the series? All four neutral and all four positive meet at the outlet receptacle.

Comment: Normally, I would use a meter to test the wires and see which one is the feed from the panel. No-Contact testers are not fine enough to show which cable is which.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Hot was going into the dimmer first. I moved hot onto the outlet, and through the outlet into the dimmer. Everything is working again.

Comment: Super! Glad things worked out.